# Count by unique pair of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to count by number of rows per unique pair of columns (ip, useragent), e.g.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'ip': ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2'], 'useragent': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']})

     ip              useragent
0    192.168.0.1     a
1    192.168.0.1     a
2    192.168.0.1     b
3    192.168.0.2     b
```

To produce:

```
ip           useragent  
192.168.0.1  a           2
192.168.0.1  b           1
192.168.0.2  b           1
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you use groupby, you will get what you want.

```
d.groupby(['ip', 'useragent']).size()
```

produces:

```
ip          useragent               
192.168.0.1 a           2
            b           1
192.168.0.2 b           1
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Missed the final step on the groupby/count/[].

Comment: For me, that just gives `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'size'`.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 0 entries
Empty DataFrame` Pandas Version 15.2

Comment: Got it: `d.groupby(['ip', 'useragent']).size()` does it :)

Comment: What if I want to count the number of unique values in each range? i.e.: in range "192.28.0.1" there are 2 unique values (a,b). In range "192.168.0.2", there is 1 unique value which is b. How could I write my code to get it?

Comment: to answer weefwefwqg3:
`d.groupby(['ip'])['useragent'].nunique()`

Comment: For me `print(d.groupby(['ip', 'useragent']).count())` prints `Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(192.168.0.1, a), (192.168.0.1, b), (192.168.0.2, b)]`

Comment: @Youda008 this is quite an old answer, it should be `.size()` now instead of `.count()`

Comment: Well `size` just produces Series where index is a string that concatenates the name of columns sent to groupby, that's not very practical. What we need is DataFrame whose first columns are the columns from groupby argument and last column is the count of occurences of these pairs, tripples, ...

Comment: @Youda008 `d.groupby(['ip', 'useragent']).size().reset_index()` will produce a dataframe

Comment: can you make $useragent$ as the column?

Answer (score 7):

```
print(d.groupby(['ip', 'useragent']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:''}))
```

gives:

```
            ip useragent   
0  192.168.0.1         a  2
1  192.168.0.1         b  1
2  192.168.0.2         b  1
```

---

Another nice option might be [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print(pd.crosstab(d.ip, d.useragent) )
print('\nsome cosmetics:')
print(pd.crosstab(d.ip, d.useragent).reset_index().rename_axis('',axis='columns') )
```

gives:

```
useragent    a  b
ip               
192.168.0.1  2  1
192.168.0.2  0  1

some cosmetics:
            ip  a  b
0  192.168.0.1  2  1
1  192.168.0.2  0  1
```

Comment: I second using groupby. I ran a test and crosstab is much slower than groupby (e.g. in my test groupby took 0.02 seconds whereas crosstab took 2.3 seconds for a dataframe of 10K records).

Comment: @pegah: I am very surprised! You can simply call the commands with the `%time` magic command in front (using ipython). I get runtimes of  16.5ms vs 18.4ms. In general, the more specific function (here `crosstab`) can be expected to perform better. Especially a runtime difference of a factor of 100 for similar calls in the same library should make one suspicious. Did you maybe calculate `crosstab` on a full `df` and select some columns after that, while you calculated the group by only on the selected columns?