# Remove duplicate reversed pairs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given a Pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
   value_1  value_2
0    b     a
1    a     b
2    c     d
3    d     c
```

I'd like to count how many times each pair ocurred, despite order. In other words a,b is equal to b,a. I found some cases, like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659881/count-by-unique-pair-of-columns-in-pandas), but in this case some values are expected to appear in only one column.

First, I try something like:

```
pd.crosstab(df.value_1,df.value_2).replace(0,np.nan).\
     stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Frequency'})
```

Through this method I also could not remove the duplicates taking into account the order `(a,b == b, a)`

Then I assume the case of a list like `[(a,b), (b,a), (c,d), (d,c)]`, so I created a function to return only the single pairs according to their elements:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_unique_pairs(pairs):
    unique_pairs = []
    for pair in combinations(pairs, 2):
        if Counter(pair[0]) == Counter(pair[1]):
            unordered_pair = set(list(pair[0]+pair[1]))
            unique_pairs.append(unordered_pair)
    return {(tuple(e)) for e in unique_pairs}
```

Their output for `[(a,b), (b,a), (c,d), (d,c)]` is `{(a,b), (c,d)}`

But, it is not viable for a big dataframe.

finally, for the dataframe described above, the expected output is:

```
   pair frequency
0    b; a   2      
1    c; d   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first sorting values per rows with [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1))
```

Then join together and use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = (df1[0] + '; ' + df1[1]).value_counts().rename_axis('pair').reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   pair  count
0  a; b      2
1  c; d      2
```

Alternative with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = (df1[0] + '; ' + df1[1])
df = s.groupby(s).size().rename_axis('pair').reset_index(name='count')
```